# What is the best strategy for setting up test data in integration tests?

Tags: repository, integration-testing, ndbunit

I'm trying to implement integration tests for my repositories and I got stuck for choosing the right strategy for inserting test data before each integration test.

This is how my repository test class looks like;

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class RealtyTest : ITest<IRealtyRepository>
  {
    public IUnitOfWork Uow { get; set; }

    public IRealtyRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public ITestEnvironment TestEnvironment { get; set; }

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetup()
    {
        TestEnvironment = new RealtyTestEnvironment();
        TestEnvironment.Prepare();
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        Uow = AppCore.Instance.RealtyUow;
        Uow.BeginTransaction();
        Repository = ((IRealtyUow)Uow).RealtyRepository;
    }

    [Test]
    public void should_get_realty_detail_by_id()
    {
        Realty realty = Repository.GetDetail(1);

        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Firm);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.FirmUser);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Category);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.SubCategory);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Publish);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.ResIdence);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Star);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Floor);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Heating);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Fuel);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.BuildState);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Usage);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Credit);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Register);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Activate);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County.City);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County.City.Country);
    }

    [Test]
    public void should_get_realty_detail_all_by_id()
    {
       Realty realty = Repository.GetWithChilds(1);

        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Firm);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.FirmUser);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Category);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.SubCategory);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Publish);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.ResIdence);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Star);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Floor);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Heating);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Fuel);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.BuildState);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Usage);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Credit);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Register);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.Activate);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County.City);
        Assert.IsNotNull(realty.District.County.City.Country);

        Assert.Greater(realty.Files.Count, 0);
        Assert.Greater(realty.Attributes.Count, 0);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        if (Uow != null)
        {
            Uow.Rollback();
            Uow.Dispose();
        }
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void OneTimeTearDown()
    {
        TestEnvironment.Rollback();
    }
}
```

As you see on OneTimeSetup() method I'm inserting test data and deleting on OneTimeTearDown() method after each integration test methods are done in test class.
For test data creation I've used NDbUnit library.

Here is my RealtyTestEnvironment class implementation;

```
 public class RealtyTestEnvironment : ITestEnvironment
{
    private NDbUnitTest _database = null;

    public int TestRowCount { get; set; }

    public RealtyTestEnvironment()
    {
        TestRowCount = 1;
    }

    public void Prepare()
    {
        _database = new SqlDbUnitTest(TestSettings.HemlakTestDbConnection);
        _database.ReadXmlSchema(string.Format(@"{0}\HemlakDb\Hemlak.xsd", TestSettings.AppRootPath));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.DeleteAll);

        GeneralTestDataBuilder generalDataBuilder = new GeneralTestDataBuilder();
        _database.ReadXml(generalDataBuilder.GetTestTypeStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);

        LocationTestDataBuilder locationDataBuilder = new LocationTestDataBuilder();
        _database.ReadXml(locationDataBuilder.GetTestCountryStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(locationDataBuilder.GetTestCityStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(locationDataBuilder.GetTestCountyStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(locationDataBuilder.GetTestDistrictStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);

        FirmTestDataBuilder firmDataBuilder = new FirmTestDataBuilder();
        _database.ReadXml(firmDataBuilder.GetTestFirmStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(firmDataBuilder.GetTestFirmUserStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);

        RealtyTestDataBuilder realtyDataBuilder = new RealtyTestDataBuilder();
        _database.ReadXml(realtyDataBuilder.GetTestRealtyStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(realtyDataBuilder.GetTestRealtyFileStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
        _database.ReadXml(realtyDataBuilder.GetTestRealtyAttributeStream(TestRowCount));
        _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.InsertIdentity);
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_database != null)
        {
            _database.PerformDbOperation(DbOperationFlag.DeleteAll);
        }
    }
}
```

So I've chosen NDbUnit but i don't feel comfortable because last commit date of the project is 3 years ago and requires too much effort for preparing test environment.

Some people use Repository class itself for inserting test data,so now we are using Repository class to insert test data for testing that Repository class?? It doesn't make sense to me.

-What are your approaches,how do you insert test data for testing your repositories?

-And how about my implementation, should I continue with Ndbunit?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to write integration tests for logic needing a data storage:

- mock data storage dependency and use it instead of a real database. Sth like NSubstitute or Moq is used often;
- use another faster database as a replacement. EF Core provides [in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/) out of the box or you could use sth like [Sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html);
- use a real database.

I personally usually choose the latter to avoid behavior discrepansies and lacking features, while using sth like in-memory database, when compared to a real one.

Then you need to initialize/cleanup your database and there are a few options here as well.

Data seeding could be implemented this way:

- each test creates entities it needs;
- reused piece of code to create all entities for all the tests at once;
- manually written sql script;
- use some libraries. I know a few: [NDbUnit](https://github.com/NDbUnit/NDbUnit), which is mentioned by you. It's somewhat outdated, but there a few more-or-less fresh forks. And there is [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) which I'm developing currently as I wasn't that happy with NDbUnit.

And also there are a few approaches to clean it up afterwards:

- create a database from scratch for every test;
- restore database from backup;
- restore database from shapshot;
- wrap tests in transaction and then revert it;
- restore changes done in each test in the same test manually;
- use insert and delete sql scripts to restore data to its initial state;
  use libraries to insert and delete data for you. [Reseed](https://github.com/v-zubritsky/Reseed) is also able to handle that and also there is [Respawn](https://github.com/jbogard/Respawn).

All these could be somehow combined to achieve the best performance. And instead of using a dedicated Sql Server you could host your databases in docker with use of sth like [TestContainers](https://github.com/HofmeisterAn/dotnet-testcontainers) and start them by tests themselves on-demand.

As for the test framework integration, the approach you've chosen fits the problem well. Attributes like `[OneTimeSetUp]`, `[OneTimeTearDown]`, `[FixtureSetUp]`, `[FixtureTearDown]`, `[SetUp]`, `[TearDown]` is a good way to execute initialization and cleanup of database before/after your tests are run.